# Casting generic types created at runtime

Tags: generics, casting, c++-cli

I want to create a generic class created at runtime to convert generic types. The version below is supposed to convert a double to an integer once instantiated and display it. The casting throws an exception which I don't why it has been thrown.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
generic<typename tht_1, typename tht_2> ref class mtac{
public:
    mtac(tht_2 par_1){
        System::Console::WriteLine(dycast(par_1)->ToString());
    };
    static tht_1 dycast(tht_2 par_1){
        tht_1 treturn;
        System::Console::WriteLine("Atempted casting of {0} to {1}", par_1->GetType()->ToString(), treturn->GetType()->ToString());
        //                                                           System::Double                System::Int32
        try{
            //next statement throws unexpected exception
            treturn = safe_cast<tht_1>(par_1);
        }
        catch(System::Exception^ e){
            System::Console::WriteLine(e->Message);
        };
        return treturn;
    };
};
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args){
    //create generic class type
    System::Type^ otype_1 = int::typeid;
    System::Type^ otype_2 = double::typeid;
    array<System::Type^>^ the_types = {otype_1,otype_2};
    System::Type^ genclass = (*(mtac::typeid)).MakeGenericType(the_types);

    //create parameter arguement list to pass onto constructor of my generic class
    array<System::Object^>^ argstoevl_1 = gcnew array<System::Object^>(1);
    argstoevl_1[0] = gcnew double;
    argstoevl_1[0] = 2.552;

    //Create an instance
    System::Object^ temp_2 = System::Activator::CreateInstance(genclass,argstoevl_1);
    System::Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
};
```

I presume `safe_cast<tht_1>(par_1);` translates to `safe_cast<int>(par_1);` once the generic method is created. Can someone please explain where I have gone wrong or correct me in my flaws of understanding generic classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with a cast, it requires a *conversion*.  The answer you got at the MSDN forums is probably not the way you want to do it after you profile your program, building and compiling an Expression is exceedingly expensive if you don't re-use it.

Get ahead by acknowledging that the types you use in your generic are convertible types and have well-defined conversions.  That is expressible by the System::IConvertible interface.  Every plain value type value implements it.  Which makes this work:

```
using namespace System;

generic<typename tht_1, typename tht_2> 
where tht_1 : IConvertible
where tht_2 : IConvertible  
ref class mtac {
public:
    mtac(tht_2 par_1) {
        System::Console::WriteLine(convert(par_1)->ToString());
    };
    static tht_1 convert(tht_2 par_1) {
        return safe_cast<tht_1>(par_1->ToType(tht_1::typeid, nullptr));
    };
};
```

The safe_cast<> now merely unboxes the value, that's not a problem.  It is not quite equivalent to Expression::Convert(), that method uses Reflection to search for user-defined conversion operators.  Very expensive of course, if you need that kind of flexibility then you'll have to pay the price.